# exclude children from taxonomy term

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, children, custom-taxonomy

Hi I have a custom post type called 'support-team-doc' and a custom taxonomy called 'support_team_docs' which have categories as follows:

```
Support Teams Group
-- Accounts
-- IT
-- Marketing
-- Risk & Compliance
```

Each category has numerous posts; I do not want posts from the sub-categories to display on any of the categories pages; atm any posts in the sub categories 'accounts, it, marketing, risk-compliance' are being displayed like this: 'support-teams-group'; I have tried the following:

```
<?php
$termsTextarea = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'support-team-doc',
    'tax_query'=>
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'support_team_docs',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $termsTextarea->slug,
            'include_children' => false,
        ),
);
$query1 = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query1->have_posts() ) : $query1->the_post(); 

    get_template_part( 'content', 'support_team_docs' );

endwhile; ?>
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

tax_query is a multi-dimensional array... you're missing one array element in your current code.  Try this:

```
<?php
$termsTextarea = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'support-team-doc',
    'tax_query'=>
        array(
           array(
               'taxonomy' => 'support_team_docs',
               'field' => 'slug',
               'terms' => $termsTextarea->slug,
               'include_children' => false
           )
        )
);
$query1 = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query1->have_posts() ) : $query1->the_post(); 

    get_template_part( 'content', 'support_team_docs' );

endwhile; ?>
```